# C++ Token defining member

Tags: c++, class

In Bjarne's book's exercises there is a definition like this which not explained in the book and I got confused. What is the equivalent for this definition please in a simpler way? Thanks!

```
Token(char ch, double val) :kind(ch), value(val) { }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: For more complex cases, you have to be aware that the initialization order is the declaration order and take that into consideration. Also, for user type with a constructor, you usually want to use the initialization list for best efficiency particularly if default constructor is not trivial (for example, allocate memory).

Comment: And by the way, in modern C++, you could also use the { } syntax to initialize objects and each syntax have their own subtilties. So reading recent books is a good idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple constructor for a `Token` which takes two arguments (a `char` and a `double`) and then initializes class members `kind` and `value` (using the constructors initialization list - which is the *right* way to do it, rather than using the constructor body) with the values passed to the constructor as `ch` and `val`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constructor of the class 'Token' which means:

```
Token(char ch, double val) {
kind = ch;
value= val;}
```

'kind' and 'value' are member data of the class.

Comment: Well, this is the simpler explanation… and for simple types, this is mostly equivalent but the are a few subtilties in more complex cases.

Comment: Using the constructor body is inefficient when you could have used the initializer list.